# Error de python y recognize_google

Tags: python-3.8

en este es mi codigo es para hacer un reconocimiento de voz y que me escriba en pantalla lo que le dije

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr
import mysql.connector
from difflib import SequenceMatcher as SM
import random
import time
recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
microphone = sr.Microphone(device_index = 0)
eng = pyttsx3.init()
eng.setProperty("rate",140)
eng.setProperty("volume",1.0)
listVoices = eng.getProperty("voices")
eng.setProperty("voice",listVoices[2].id)
def recognizeMicAudio():
    palabra=""
    print("escuchando..")
    with microphone as source:
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)
        palabra = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, lenguage="es-ES")
    return palabra

print(recognizeMicAudio())
```

y cuando pongo el micrófono para poder hablar para que me lo imprima me sale el siguiente error

```
escuchando..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\Reconocimiento Facial\voz\ReconocimientoDeVoz.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(recognizeMicAudio())
  File "C:\Users\oscar\Desktop\Reconocimiento Facial\voz\ReconocimientoDeVoz.py", line 19, in recognizeMicAudio
    palabra = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, lenguage="es-ES")
TypeError: recognize_google() got an unexpected keyword argument 'lenguage'
[Finished in 6.5s]
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta en vez de `palabra = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, lenguage="es-ES")`  por  `palabra = recognizer.recognize_google(audio, language="es-ES")`

el unico cambio es que "lenguage" no es reconocido como argumento ya que esta en español, en ingles seria "language".